# Removing Flickr account from Photos app of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-photos-app

I am using Windows 8 which comes with a "Photos" application capable of connecting to different cloud services like Flickr, SkyDrive, Facebook, etc. to display your photos.

I've entered my Flickr account information to this app and let it display access my account to display my photos, now I want to disconnect it. How can I do it?

Comment: If I remember correctly they are stored under your user profile and not the actual application. Not in front of Windows 8 and can't confirm right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disconnect flickr account from the photos application, one must follow the steps below.

1. Open Photos Application
2. Press Windows + C and select "Settings"
3. Select "Options"
4. Select "Options" next to Flickr item (Web page opens, profile.live.com)
5. login to your live account if needed
6. Remove flickr account int the page

Answer (score 1):

You can simply revoke access from Windows 8 in your Flickr account settings:

1. Go to [settings of Flickr account](http://www.flickr.com/account).
2. Click [**Sharing & Extending**](http://www.flickr.com/account/sharing/) tab.
3. Click [**Edit**](http://www.flickr.com/services/auth/list.gne?from=extend) in the **Account links** section.
4. You will see the list of the applications you've given access to your account.
   One of them is **Microsoft**, http://aka.ms/flickr.
5. Click **Remove permission?** next to Microsoft to revoke the access.

Alternatively you can go to http://aka.ms/flickr, clear the *View your photos and videos from Flickr* check box, and click **Save**.
<sub>This page is displayed in Russian for me, and I translated the titles, so the real interface text could slightly differ.</sub>